# What choices should I consider for investing money that I will need in two years?

Tags: investing, short-term

I have around 100k in cash that I would like to put to work.

Property I've heard breaks even after 3 years, so this is not an option.

I do not know enough about the stock market to want to gamble there.

What would you suggest I look at for high returns (high risk is fine), as I want to put the money to work before immigration.

Thanks.

Comment: Two years, but do you *NEED* the money at the end of 2 years, or is this all extra money laying around?  I would assume that your timeline means you can't really stand to lose this money.

Comment: Does your high risk tolerance include the loss of capital over the two years or not?

Comment: I need the money at the end of two years. The high risk includes the loss of the actual capital.

Comment: but with high risk you may have no money left. i wouldn't invest any money that you need. whether short term or long term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Never** invest money you need in the short term.

As already suggested, park your money in CDs.

Answer (score 3):

Books such as "[The Pocket Idiot's Guide to Investing in Mutual Funds](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592576303)" claim that money market funds and CDs are the most prudent things to invest in if you need the money within 5 years. More specifically:

- 2 years = cash equivalent (money market fund or CD)
- 2 to 5 years = bond mutual fund or balanced mutual fund
- 5 or more years = stock mutual fund

Comment: Could you elaborate on what CDs are?

Comment: @Forkrul Assail - Certificate of Deposit, issued by banks to confirm you have deposited certain sum of money.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to South Africa or from?  (Looking on your profile for this info.)

If you're going to South Africa, you could do worse than to buy five or six one-ounce krugerrands.  Maybe wait until next year to buy a few; you may get a slightly better deal.

Not only is it gold, it's minted by that country, so it's easier to liquidate should you need to.  Plus, they go for a smaller premium in the US than some other forms of gold.

As for the rest of the $100k, I don't know ... either park it in CD ladders or put it in something that benefits if the economy gets worse.

(Cheery, ain't I? ;) )

Comment: Yes, from South Africa. I'll have a look at CD ladders.

Answer (score 2):

If you ever need the money in three years, imagine that **today is 2006 and you need the money in 2009**.  Keep it in savings accounts, money-markets, or CDs maturing at the right time.

Answer (score -4):

Investing $100k into physical gold (bars or coins) is the most prudent option; given the state of economic turmoil worldwide.

Take a look at the long term charts; they're pretty self explanatory.   Gold has an upward trend for 100+ years. 
http://www.goldbuyguide.com/price/

A more high risk/high reward investment would be to buy $100k of physical silver.  Silver has a similar track record and inherent benefits of gold.  Yet, with a combination of factors that could make it even more bull than gold (ie- better liquidity, industrial demand).

Beyond that, you may want to look at other commodities such as oil and agriculture.

The point is, this is troubled times for worldwide economies.  Times like this you want to invest in REAL things like commodities or companies that are actually producing essential materials.

Comment: Ugh. Buying into a bubble seems a little TOO high risk.

Comment: Did you not see the charts?  There is no bubble in gold or silver, these are assets that have been traded for thousands of years.   The biggest bubble of all is fiat currency; particularly the US dollar.  We are witnessing it's demise and quite possibly the bursting of the biggest bubble in history.

Comment: Gold has serious volatility, so while I think it is a prudent investment for long-term (disclosure: long gold) for 2 years you may very well come out at loss, especially given that now we have everybody and his dog talking about gold, which is usually a sign of overheating...

Comment: The posting from GoldNerd @ The Gold Buying Guide might not be the epitome of unbiased reporting.

Comment: It does seem like there has been a steady incline which would dictate an eventual drop?

Comment: All I've got to say about this is look at all the radio ads for people jumping up and down about buying gold as an investment. Buying an investment when everyone is hyping it is historically a really bad idea.

Comment: I think it's unfair to give -1 to this answer. Whether you agree or not it's a valid option. If every day gold changes hands of 100K people then 100K people think it may go up and 100K think it may go down. If you disagree - short it.

Comment: @vitalik It absolutely is **not** the most prudent option, especially for money that will be needed in the short term.  (Never mind the risk with any investment, physical gold needs to be stored and secured.  $100k worth of gold will typically not be stored at home.)  The crucial point for this question is the fact that this money will be needed in two years.  This money should absolutely not be invested, but rather parked somewhere safe.  (On a side-note, sympathy voting undermines the whole point of voting on answers.  If you really think the answer deserves an up-vote, that is fine.)

Comment: @George However he is fine taking risk ("high risk"), meaning to lose some of his capital. I think it's a valid suggestion.

Comment: @vitalik That's fine, if you believe it is a suggestion that deserves an up-vote.  Personally, I took issue with the claim that it was the most prudent option, which it is not.  Investing money you need in the short term is never a good idea.